# thrust::make_zip_iterator - What happens with inconsistent iterator ranges?

Tags: c++, boost, thrust

I am currently trying to understand the following example of the boost library that uses parallel processing with thrust.

```cpp
struct lorenz_system
{
    struct lorenz_functor
    {
        template< class T >
        __host__ __device__
        void operator()( T t ) const
        {
            // unpack the parameter we want to vary and the Lorenz variables
            value_type R = thrust::get< 3 >( t );
            value_type x = thrust::get< 0 >( t );
            value_type y = thrust::get< 1 >( t );
            value_type z = thrust::get< 2 >( t );
            thrust::get< 4 >( t ) = sigma * ( y - x );
            thrust::get< 5 >( t ) = R * x - y - x * z;
            thrust::get< 6 >( t ) = -b * z + x * y ;

        }
    };

    lorenz_system( size_t N , const state_type &beta )
    : m_N( N ) , m_beta( beta ) { }

    template< class State , class Deriv >
    void operator()(  const State &x , Deriv &dxdt , value_type t ) const
    {
        thrust::for_each(
                thrust::make_zip_iterator( thrust::make_tuple(
                        boost::begin( x ) ,
                        boost::begin( x ) + m_N ,
                        boost::begin( x ) + 2 * m_N ,
                        m_beta.begin() ,
                        boost::begin( dxdt ) ,
                        boost::begin( dxdt ) + m_N ,
                        boost::begin( dxdt ) + 2 * m_N  ) ) ,
                thrust::make_zip_iterator( thrust::make_tuple(
                        boost::begin( x ) + m_N ,
                        boost::begin( x ) + 2 * m_N ,
                        boost::begin( x ) + 3 * m_N ,
                        m_beta.begin() ,
                        boost::begin( dxdt ) + m_N ,
                        boost::begin( dxdt ) + 2 * m_N ,
                        boost::begin( dxdt ) + 3 * m_N  ) ) ,
                lorenz_functor() );
    }
    size_t m_N;
    const state_type &m_beta;
};
```

This example can be fully explored at:

https://github.com/headmyshoulder/odeint-v2/blob/master/examples/thrust/lorenz_parameters.cu

I am still pretty new to C++, but have done introductory courses in C, and also learned programming in Java. So, I am mostly familiar with the concepts.

My question would be in the second operator overwrite. As far as I understand, `thrust::for_each()` takes two iterators, one where it starts and one where it ends, as well as a functor. When `thrust::make_zip_iterator()` gets called, it creates a `zip_iterator`. As far as I understand, `zip_iterator` creates a moving reference for the entire bundle. For this, it requires that the length are all the same.

However `m_beta.begin()` appears in both iterators with no change whatsoever. Shouldn't this mean that `m_beta` consists of only one value (which is 0, if you check the full code on GitHub) and therefore the `zip_iterator` fails?

I ran the code and it works beautifully though, so what am I not understanding about `zip_iterator`s, or specifically thrust's?

Comment: I'm not sure, but a possible explanation is that the difference between two zip iterators is just calculated from the first iterator in each one and so all the other ones just don't matter at all. I.e. the code is "wrong" but not buggy and the values of `m_beta` are iterated over normally.

Comment: [Bingo](https://github.com/NVIDIA/thrust/blob/main/thrust/iterator/detail/zip_iterator.inl#L131)

Comment: Thanks. This is honestly stupid. Mind posting this as an answer, so that i can accept?

Comment: *So, I am mostly familiar with the concepts.* That's what I thought when I moved to C++ from C and Java. This is a time to be cautious and confirm assumptions before you find yourself with a backlog of code that sort-of works or is overcomplicated because of bolt-ons to work around problems that arise when the C++ way and the C or Java way diverge.

Comment: The concepts of programming still exist. What works in C++ of course is very specific. I will learn that parallely but for now i need to write some parameter studies that can be run in a few hours instead of days on my end. Using Boost and Thrust should help get familiar with advanced concepts of C++ like its usage of operator overwrites, as in functors.

Comment: A way to improve the code and generally avoid this kind of issuue would be to only create a single zip iterator in a temporary `auto iter = thrust::make_zip_iterator(...)` and then pass `iter` and `iter + m_N` to the algorithm. This would be DRYer in my opinion. Another great tool for increasing readability with zip iterators is using `thrust::make_zip_function` on the operator to get rid of all the `get`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case (probably in all parallel cases) Thrust only needs the "end" iterator to compute the distance to the "begin" iterator. For the zip iterator this is [implemented at the moment](https://github.com/NVIDIA/thrust/blob/ae08f98153e0fa69d535e988bfd8775435740e34/thrust/iterator/detail/zip_iterator.inl#L131) as

```cpp
__thrust_exec_check_disable__
template<typename IteratorTuple>
  template <typename OtherIteratorTuple>
  __host__ __device__
    typename zip_iterator<IteratorTuple>::super_t::difference_type
      zip_iterator<IteratorTuple>
        ::distance_to(const zip_iterator<OtherIteratorTuple> &other) const
{
  return get<0>(other.get_iterator_tuple()) - get<0>(get_iterator_tuple());
} // end zip_iterator::distance_to()
```

I.e. only the first "end" iterator is used, all others are ignored. **This is an implementation detail and should therefore not be relied upon.** One could argue that at least in a debug build the difference should be computed for all pairs of iterators and an exception should be thrown if any pair produces something different from the others.

In short the code in the question works (for now), but it should be fixed to avoid relying on implementation details and to make it clearer to the reader that `m_beta` is iterated over and not just the first element used, as a beginner might think at first glance.

> Shouldn't this mean that `m_beta` consists of only one value [...]?

If it would work that way it would mean that `m_beta` had zero elements because the end iterator is one past the last element.